# "While I was going to school" vs "While I went to school"

Tags: tense

> While I was going to school, I met him.

> While I went to school, I met him.

Is there be any difference?

Comment: _While I was going to school_ could mean either _while I was on my way to school_ or _during the years that I was attending school_. _While I went to  school_ is not very idiomatic English. If anything, it would have the second meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence makes sense.  You were on your way to school and you met someone.  Since you are using the objective pronoun *him*, it is clear that the listener already knows who you are referring to.

> 1. While I was going to school, I met him.
> 2. While I went to school, I met him.

The second sentence is a mess. It could mean that during the time that you attended school, you met him.

To answer your question:  yes, the sentences are different.

Try these:

I met him at school.

I met him when I was in high school.

We met at school.

We met when we were in high school.

***Going to school*** can mean ***attend school*** or ***travel to school***!

### Travel

We met on the bus.

We met on the school bus.

I met him on the way to school.

While walking to school, I met this guy.

### Attending school

While going to school, I became friends with him.

We met and became friends at school.

Comment: Thx. "Walking to school, I met this guy." could be okay?

Comment: @Brandon  Yes, it is good.